# Docker authentication in Gitlab with AWS autoscale

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am having the hardest time working with Docker credentials with Gitlab.

The set up:

Gitlab runners are auto scaled on AWS. See here: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws/

This is my configuration file (I have slimmed it down to remove things like tags, VPC etc):

```
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 30

[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-runner"
  limit = 3
  url = "https://test.somedomain.com"
  id = 18
  token = "12345678"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-01-12T06:08:06Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Shared = true
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      BucketName = "gitlab-runner"
      BucketLocation = "us-east-1"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 1
    IdleScaleFactor = 0.0
    IdleCountMin = 0
    IdleTime = 1800
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "runner-autoscale-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
      "amazonec2-region=us-east-1",
      "amazonec2-ami=ami-09cd747c78a9add63",
      "amazonec2-security-group=test-sg",
      "amazonec2-instance-type=t3.large",
      "amazonec2-root-size=100",
    ]
  [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
    Periods = ["* * 1-17 * * mon-fri *"]
    IdleCount = 1
    IdleTime = 3600
    Timezone = "UTC"
  [[runners.machine.autoscaling]]
    Periods = ["* * * * * sat,sun *"]
    IdleCount = 0
    IdleTime = 3600
    Timezone = "UTC"
```

My gitlab runner manager machine (where docker-machine is running which spanws these runners) has the configuration under: /root/.docker/config.json

That file looks like this:

```
{
    "auths": {
            "index.docker.io": {
                    "auth": "123"
            }
    }
}
```

I have also added the **DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG** in the project so to be sure.

The problem:

I get the beloe error messages every now and then in our pipelines:

```
toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

Have a look at the error below. I have crossed out sensitive info.

[image]

We are on a Docker Pro account so we cannot be on reaching this limit. We are on 100s a day, certainly not 5000 a day.